# In Google Analytics can you track multiple goals in a session

Tags: google-analytics

There are 2 possible actions to take on my website - to download a whitepaper or to sign-up for my newletter. Each of these actions have their own unique thank-you page and I have set them up as INDIVIDUAL goals (Goal 1 = download, Goal 2= Newsletter signup).

My question is "If someone comes to my website and first downloads a whitepaper (goal #1) and then signs up for a newsletter (goal #2), how will GA report this?

I know that GA only captures 1 instance of a goal, so for example if I downloaded 5 whitepapers it would only count as 1 download. But in my testing it appears that GA only captures the first goal and not the second (even if the second goal is DIFFERENT FROM THE FIRST GOAL). So in my example above it would count 1 download and NO newsletter sign-up.

Is this correct?!? and if so, any idea for how to get around it? Just because someone did one goal on my site doesn't mean I don't want to know about the other goals they completed...

Comment: Would you post your goal URLs ?
I've strange behavior recently about goals

Answer (score 0):

All evidence, both documented and personal, seems to indicate that Google Analytics will allow you to track multiple *different* goals in the same session. If the second goal isn't recording, I'd take a look at the goal configuration, and make sure its correctly configured, as they can be very tricky to get right. It's very likely that that's your culprit.

Some evidence [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=6e4fce2f8f7a26bb&hl=en), [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=564faf17684a03fb&hl=en).

The only limitation like this is that a single, *particular* goal can only be counted once per session.

Answer (score -1):

Greg - the usual way to work around this is to switch on ecommerce tracking, and treat each goal as a separate product, and view in the ecommerce reports, rather than the more limited goal reports.